# How to apply multi-loop in a google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have Idea of simple loop for example if I have a cell value in "A1" = "c" and I have another set of values that I want to match in "B:B".

```
var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
var match = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

var dataRange = targetSheet.getRange(B1:B5).getValues(); //doubt here too
for(var i=0;i<dataRange.length;i++) {

    if(dataRange[i][0] == match) 
{ Do something }
                        }

    A     B
------------
1   c     x
2         c
3         b
```

However, I have very less idea on how to perform the same if I have multiple values to match.

```
    A     B
1   z     x
2   x     c
3   c     b
4   v
5   b
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I want to match values from A to B column if match exist then {do something}. for example if x found in column B then {do something} if c found in columnB {do something else}. my code should match values from A to B one by one first it will look for z then x then c and so on. On each match {do something}.

Comment: But do you have an explicit action you want to take if value "A" is in both columns A and B or do you just want to define an action to take when a value from column A exists in column B?

Comment: I just want to define an action to take when a value from column A exists in column B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood this correctly you want to loop through column `A` and if there is a set value there, you want to look for the same value in column `B`. This is a simple matter of a loop inside of a loop. Let's say you have the 2 columns in 1 array

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues() //this will get columns A and B until the last row with data into a 2D array

  var i, ii;

  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == '') break;  // if first column is empty we stop looking for the next one, you can get rid of this

    for (ii = 0; ii < values.length; ii++) {
      if (values[ii][1] == '') break; //if last entry reached we stop, same as before

      if (values[i][0] == values[ii][1]) {
        /* This is the part where you do what you want
        to do when you find a match, for example change background to red */
        sheet.getRange(ii + 1, 2).setBackground('red')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** as per requester I have amended the function. This is essentially a difference in your `if` statement and where it is as we are now only concerned with checking if something exists in B column, we no longer need an `if` in the first loop. The one I have put in there is for situations where you intend to let's say have 3 entries in column A, however 7 entries in column B. Same thing for the reverse scenario. Otherwise you can get rid of the `if` statements immediately after the `for` statement. That is done because `getLastRow()` will take the last row that has data on the sheet. Keep in mind that if you have only 3 values in column A and 7 in column B, but you have a value in C10 then `getLastRow() = 10`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Vytautas!

Comment: However "chkVal" should not be a variable but values from column A itself. can you please edit your answer.

Comment: @Mask so just to be clear, you want the loop to check each value in column A if it exists in column B?

Comment: Yes exactly I want the loop to check each value in column A if it exists in column B and if exist do something.

Comment: @Mask there you go. If that works for you, consider marking the answer as correct